# Fullcalendar duplicate insert and delete

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar v4. When i select an event it shows a modal with some info about the event. If i click away from the modal it disappears. But if i delete an other event after that it deletes both events. This happens with all the events i've clicked on before. So it can deletes multiple events at once.

When i'm inserting an event into the database for the first time it is fine. But when i do this the second time the script for inserting is called twice. And when i insert the third event it's called three times.

I can't find a way to get the old actions out of the memory. I've tried to call the calendar.unselect() method, but i can't get it to work.

Here is my select and delete code.

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    var event = info.event;
    $.ajax({
        url:"select.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: { id: event.id },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#exampleModal1").modal();
            document.getElementById("title1").value = (data['title']); 
            document.getElementById("trainer1").value = (data['trainer']); 
        }
    });

    $('#deleteButton').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"delete.php",
            type:"POST",
            data: { id: event.id },
            success: function() {
                $('#exampleModal1').modal('hide');

                calendar.refetchEvents()
            }
        });
    });

    $('#annuleer').on('click', function(){
        calendar.unselect()
    });
},
```

Comment: Please make sure that your each events has unique id.

Comment: Each event has an unique id in the database. The insert.php file is called multiple times. This also happens with the delete.php file. This is why there are multiple inserts and deletes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are creating a new event handler on your delete button every time eventClick happens. That isn't necessary.

Define the handler once when your script first runs.

Either that or clear all previous handlers before you define a new one.

Otherwise all the previously created handlers will run at the same time whenever you click the button, which explains why other events you had clicked on previously are also being deleted.

Comment: Thanks (again)! I changed it to .off().on('click' and that does the trick.